# How to limit the pan gesture movement in swift

Tags: swift, swiftui, view, gesture

I am learning Swift and I have created the typical map background where you are able to put the things

[Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQABi.png)

I have added the pan gesture but I don't like how it works, because it move out of limits of my background. I want my Background to be rebuilt with some new lines (I think this is difficult) or to limit the pan only to the background limits.

I have this code for the ContentView:

```
//
//  ContentView.swift
//  DoIt!
//
//  Created by Jesus Mariscal on 28/8/23.
//

import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var pan: CGOffset = .zero
    @GestureState private var gesturePan: CGOffset = .zero
    var body: some View {
        BackGroundMap().stroke(Color.gray)
            .offset(pan + gesturePan)
            .gesture(DesplazamientoGesto)
            
    }
    
    private var DesplazamientoGesto : some Gesture {
        
        DragGesture()
            .updating ($gesturePan) { value, gesturePan, _ in
            gesturePan = value.translation}
            .onEnded { value in
            pan += value.translation
                
            }

    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

And this is the code to create the Background:

```
import SwiftUI


struct BackGroundMap : Shape {
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var path = Path()
        let totalheightSpace = rect.height
        let totalWidthhSpace = rect.width
        let lineasExpected = expectedLines(rect: rect)
        let spaceBetweenHeightLines: Int = Int(trunc(totalWidthhSpace / lineasExpected[0]))
        let spaceBetweenHorizontalLines: Int = Int(trunc(totalheightSpace / lineasExpected[1]))
        
        for i in 0...Int(lineasExpected[0]) {
            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: CGFloat(spaceBetweenHeightLines * i), y: 0))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: CGFloat(spaceBetweenHeightLines * i), y: rect.maxY))
        }
        
        for i in 0...Int(lineasExpected[1]) {
            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: CGFloat(spaceBetweenHorizontalLines * i)))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: CGFloat(spaceBetweenHorizontalLines * i)))
        }
        
        
        
        return path
    }
    
    private func expectedLines(rect: CGRect) -> [CGFloat] {
        var lineas : [CGFloat] = []
        
        let espacioDisponibelHorizontal = rect.width
        let espacioDisponibleVertical = rect.height
        
        let CuadradosDe10px: CGFloat = 40
        
        lineas.append((1*espacioDisponibelHorizontal) / CuadradosDe10px)
        lineas.append((1*espacioDisponibleVertical) / CuadradosDe10px)
        
        
        return lineas
    }
    
    
}
```

I also have some extensions:

```
import SwiftUI

typealias CGOffset = CGSize

extension CGRect {
    var center: CGPoint {
        CGPoint(x: midX, y: midY)
    }
    init(center: CGPoint, size: CGSize) {
        self.init(origin: CGPoint(x: center.x-size.width/2, y: center.y-size.height/2), size: size)
    }
}

extension CGOffset {
    static func +(lhs: CGOffset, rhs: CGOffset) -> CGOffset {
        CGOffset(width: lhs.width + rhs.width, height: lhs.height + rhs.height)
    }
    static func +=(lhs: inout CGOffset, rhs: CGOffset) {
        lhs = lhs + rhs
    }
}
```

I have tried to limit the gesture with this code:

```
func handlePan(pan: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    switch pan.state {
    case .Began:
        if CGRectContainsPoint(self.pannableView.frame, pan.locationInView(self.pannableView)) {
            // Gesture started inside the pannable view. Do your thing.
        }
}
```

But I have not been able to adapt it to my code (I don't really understand what it does and where to put it.)

Comment: This is SwiftUI. You should add the SwiftUI tag to your question.